# Background color start down the y-axis?

Tags: css, background, background-color

I want the background color of a div to start 40px from the top of the div. Can I do this with background-color? Or do I need to use a background image (say, a 1x1px gif in the color I want, repeating it and starting the repeat 40px down)?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `Background-color`. 
The problem is that you would have to have 2 divs one in another.
the first one - the "big picture"
the second one - the div with the background color setting to it.
and give the second div that margin you wanted.
that is if i got you right :)

Good luck,
Eliran.